# Visual Studio (Xamarin) Main.axml error message "resources that were not compiled successfully"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I just installed Xamarin (Visual Studio). But I have a problem:
When I start a new Android project (Blank app) and I open the `Main.axml` there is this message:

> This project contains resources that were not compiled successfully, rendering might be affected

Maybe it's easy to solve, but I can't find out what the solution is.
Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same issue. I was fine until xamarin started to crash so I got the updated version thinking that it would solve the issue but I have been chasing my tail. Check to see if the NDK was blown away too. I found that to be an issue. I downloaded it and had to manually pull all the files out of it and put it into the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android folder. You can check it under tool: Options: and scroll down to Xamarin. it should be selected. I have a support call into Microsoft and I hope to hear from then tomorrow afternoon EST.

Comment: You will have to download the NDK and rename the zip file to a shorter name or it may not unzip. Then unzip it and put the folder in the same directory that android.sdk is in.  You should also go to the Xamarin Installer and verify that the workloads and Individual components are selected correctly. Mine had a lot added that I didn't have selected before.  Also verify what the Android Version you are using in the project's properties and verify the Android Application, Manifest, etc are all correct.  The update modified my targets. I did not try to un/re- install but that might work as well.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, still the same problem. Does this solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but I've just run into this issue as well.

The following fixed the problem:

1. Update Xamarain.Android.Support.Design in the NuGet packages.
2. Ensure that the Android SDK Manager version of build tools matches.
3. Restart VS for good measure.

Comment: Just restarting VS fixed it for me. So infuriating when they don't tell you WHAT resources were not compiled correctly.